# Convert Preg_match_all Array Output Into String

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i am trying to match content so i use preg_match_all.

**1- i am using preg_match_all to match.**

```
if(preg_match_all('/\<li class=\"relItem ur\">(.*?)\<\/li>/is',$content,$abtractmatch,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
```

**2- I am displaying It using Print_r.**

**3 Result is**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
Not There
[1] =>
Hai
[2] =>
Chennai 
[3] =>
Chennai Telephone Directory
```

4- My Aim is I need to Display it as 
hai,chennai,chennai telephone directry.

**Things I Tried:**
1-I am matching the content so i cant use implode , If i use the result is just( Array,array,array)

I need your help pls suggest me a code or Tell me the way.

Comment: Why can't you use `echo join(',',$abtractmatch[0]);`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `implode()` by passing the index of your matched array.

```
echo implode(',',$abtractmatch[0]);
```

I assume that , you imploded the `$abtractmatch` array without passing the index.

Comment: It should be `$abtractmatch[1]` if you want to join as the OP wanted. `[0]` is pointing towards the whole pattern match, i.e. `blabla</li>` where `[1]` pointing to `blablabla`.